# How to fix below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1. (React Native Maps)

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new developing in react-native I have problem installing the react-native-maps to my project

In https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

They say I need to change root build.gradle by replacing of this code

```
    ext {
    compileSdkVersion   = 26
    targetSdkVersion    = 26
    buildToolsVersion   = "26.0.2"
    supportLibVersion   = "26.1.0"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
}
```

Now after i change my build.gradle to this

```
// ext {
    //     buildToolsVersion = "28.0.2"
    //     minSdkVersion = 16
    //     compileSdkVersion = 28
    //     targetSdkVersion = 27
    //     supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    // }
    ext {
        compileSdkVersion   = 26
        targetSdkVersion    = 26
        minSdkVersion = 16
        buildToolsVersion   = "26.0.2"
        supportLibVersion   = "26.1.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "11.8.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "0.5+"
    }
```

I got a 2 error found after i re run my application

> > > Configure project :app WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the minimum
> > >       supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1. Android
> > >       SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove
> > >       "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as each
> > >       version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the
> > >       build tools.
> >
> > Configure project :react-native-maps WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (26.0.2) is ignored, as it is below the
> >     minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
> >     Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning,
> >     remove "buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'" from your build.gradle file, as
> >     each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of
> >     the build tools.
> >
> > Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED Error: Cannot create directory C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of output files for task ':app:mergeDebugResources' property 'incrementalFolder' during
>     up-to-date check.
>
>   > Could not read path 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values'.
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 21s 14 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 5 up-to-date
>   Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for
>   details. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device
>   connected and have set up your Android development environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
>
> Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
>
> Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
>       at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:637:11)
>       at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:655:13)
>       at runOnAllDevices (C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
>       at buildAndRun (C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
>       at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\xampp\htdocs\Tracker\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:81:5)

Can you help me guys how can I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I fixed the same with following:

```
compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
```